# NodeJs for loop moving too fast

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help solving a problem in my code where the for loop runs too fast and disregards the code inside it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    SendPHtml = "";
    for (var e = CurrentGame; e >= CurrentGame - 4; e--) {
        //console.log(d); // acutally does work
        (function () {
            var k = e;
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM `game" + e + "` ORDER BY id;", function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                SteamIdCheck = "";
                ItemsAdd = 0;
                ItemCostT = 0;
                SendPHtml += '<div class="round">';
                //console.log(k);
                //console.log(CurrentGame);
                if(CurrentGame != k) {
                    SendPHtml += '<div class="winner"><div class="winner-background"></div><div class="winner-wrapper">';
                    SendPHtml += '<p class="winner-text text-center"><img src="' + ServerWidePData[GameHistory[k].userid].avatar + '" alt="" rel="nofollow"> ' + ServerWidePData[GameHistory[k].userid].name + ' won $' + GameHistory[k].cost + ' with a chance of ' + GameHistory[k].percent + '%</p>';
                    SendPHtml += '<p class="winner-info text-left">Total Items: ' + GameHistory[k].itemsnum + ' | Percentage: ' + GameHistory[k].module + '%</p></div></div>';
                }
                for (var d = 0; d < rows.length; d++) {

                    (function () {
                        var gg = d;
                        if(gg == 0) {
                            ItemsAdd = 0;
                            ItemCostT = 0;
                            ItemCostT = ItemCostT + rows[gg].cost;
                            SteamIdCheck = rows[gg].userid;
                            //console.log("Clean: " + SteamIdCheck);
                            AddStart = true;
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="bet"> <table class="table-bet"><tbody><tr> <td class="level hidden-xs hidden-sm">';
                            SendPHtml += '<span>' + ServerWidePData[rows[gg].userid].level + '</span> </td> <td class="icon"> <img src="#AVATARIMG" alt="Icon" rel="nofollow" style="border-bottom:3px solid #955ad3;">';
                            SendPHtml += '</td> <td>Icessss deposited PENISCABOTAGE skins valued at $35.46</td> <td onclick="DisplayItems(\'citems\')" class="time"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></td>';
                            SendPHtml += '</tr></tbody></table><div id="citems" class="items" style="display: none;"> ';
                        }
                        if(rows[gg].userid == SteamIdCheck) {
                            ItemsAdd++;
                            console.log("Clean: " + SteamIdCheck);
                            ItemCostT = ItemCostT + rows[gg].cost;
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">';
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="item"> <img src="#ITEMPICTURE" alt="" class="img-responsive" rel="nofollow" width="120" height="100"> <div class="price">$2</div>';
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="name">' + rows[gg].item + '</div> </div> </div>';
                        } else {
                            SteamIdCheck = rows[gg].userid;
                            ItemCostT = ItemCostT + rows[gg].cost;
                            if(AddStart) {

                                SendPHtml = SendPHtml.replace("PENISCABOTAGE", ItemsAdd);
                                AddStart = false;
                            }
                            ItemsAdd = 0;
                            ItemsAdd++;
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">';
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="item"> <img src="#ITEMPICTURE" alt="" class="img-responsive" rel="nofollow" width="120" height="100"> <div class="price">$2</div>';
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="name">StatTrak™ USP-S | Torque (Minimal Wear)</div> </div> </div>';
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="clearfix"></div> </div> </div>';
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="bet"> <table class="table-bet"><tbody><tr> <td class="level hidden-xs hidden-sm">';
                            SendPHtml += '<span>' + ServerWidePData[rows[gg].userid].level + '</span> </td> <td class="icon"> <img src="#AVATARIMG" alt="Icon" rel="nofollow" style="border-bottom:3px solid #955ad3;">';
                            SendPHtml += '</td> <td>Ice deposited ' + ItemsAdd + ' skins valued at $35.46</td> <td onclick="DisplayItems(\'citems\')" class="time"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></td>';
                            SendPHtml += '</tr></tbody></table><div id="citems" class="items" style="display: none;"> ';

                        }
                        if( gg == rows.length - 1 ) {
                            SendPHtml += '<div class="clearfix"></div> </div> </div>';
                        }
                    }());
                }
                SendPHtml += '<div class="new"><h3>New round started</h3><h4>Game: ' + k + '</h4></div>';
                SendPHtml += '</div>';
            });
        }());
    }

    console.log("Current player list...");
}, 2000);
```

When this part of the code runs i get

```
Clean: 76561198100159702
Clean: 76561198062051242
Clean: 76561198072300099
Clean: 76561198072300099
Clean: 76561198072300099
Clean: 76561198072300099
Clean: 76561198072300099
Clean: 76561198072300099
Clean: 76561198072300099
```

When i should be getting more than just 76561198072300099 spammed at the end.

Comment: That's some extreme indentation. You might want to edit your code to be more reader friendly.

Comment: how is it moving too fast? and which loop is moving too fast? the `for e` or `for d` loop? not that there's anything in those loops to "slow" them down at all, so my question is really out of curiosity to know which loop you think should be going "slower"

Comment: for d does not output correct info when console.log("Clean: " + SteamIdCheck);

Comment: yeah, you say that ... but you also said it's **moving too fast** ... which loop is **moving too fast** and how **fast** do you expect it to go?

Comment: Also sorry for the indents i just copied part of my code not all of it :(

Comment: The for d loop moves too fast that it reaches the end of the mysql row so the number is the same for most of the loop when it's not supposed to be

Comment: nope, the for d loop loops through the rows 1 at a time, no reason for that loop to **slow down** (no reason for the IIFE either, no scope issue there) - your problem must be in the data retrieved by the query

Comment: what is in the `rows`? You must post it as well. Besides I guess you want to keep the async function in the loop.

Comment: Oh I see the problem - you have global variables `StreemIdCheck`, `ItemsAdd`, `ItemCostT` and `SendPHtml` - maybe some more ... no telling what your code will do because you have 5 asynchronous requests which could "finish" in any order, meaning the 5 lots of processing could be done in any order, so only you know what that would do to the data ... oh and even if they are not "globals" as such, they are declared outside of the `connection.query` callback, so they may as well be globals in that respect

Comment: Here is the data that it pulls from mysql http://pastebin.com/Syg2x6PN It should be ending with a 76561198062051242. So what should i do if i want to use global variables in the for loop?

Comment: If i do console.log("Clean: " + rows[gg].userid); and i put it inside then it displays the correct data but when i try to compare SteamIdCheck It does not work for some reason